# Get hours difference from the Start Monday and End Monday from Business hours

Tags: apex

I am still not able to get the correct difference, really struggling to make it working. The business hour set from 10 AM to 7 PM

```
BusinessHours bh = [SELECT FridayEndTime,FridayStartTime,Id,MondayEndTime,MondayStartTime,
                    FROM BusinessHours where Name='Test Business Hour'
                    LIMIT 1];
Time startTime = bh.MondayStartTime;       
Time endTime = bh.MondayEndTime;

Date d = Date.today();
Datetime monTodaystart = Datetime.newInstance(d.year(),d.month(),d.day(),startTime.hour(), startTime.minute(),startTime.second());
Datetime monTodayend = Datetime.newInstance(d.year(),d.month(),d.day(),endTime.hour(), endTime.minute(),endTime.second());
System.debug('monTodaystart :: '+monTodaystart);    
System.debug('monTodayend :: '+monTodayend); 

Long diff = BusinessHours.diff(bh.Id, monTodaystart, monTodayend);
System.debug('diff  :: '+diff);
```

I tried this simple example, but still its not working why ? How we can manipulate it ?

```
Datetime monTodaystart = Datetime.newInstance(2017,8,20,10,0,0);
Datetime monTodayEnd = Datetime.newInstance(2017,8,20,17,0,0);
System.debug('ID : '+bh.Id);

Long diff = BusinessHours.diff(bh.Id, monTodaystart,monTodayEnd);
System.debug('diff  :: '+diff);
```

I dont think I should used the API here, instead I should use my custom logic, looks like some bug in the API still exists.

[image]

Comment: What value did you get? What were you expecting to get?

Comment: I am expected to get 9 hours, but I am getting 0 hours why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A value of zero means that BusinessHours.diff calculated there was 0 elapsed "business milliseconds" between the two times according to the business hours settings. 8/20/2017 happens to be a Sunday, so if Sunday was set to "no hours", then you'd get no elapsed time. Try using 8/21/2017, or set your SundayStartTime and SundayEndTime (and adjust your code accordingly). Also check your time zone settings versus the time zone settings of the BusinessHours, as that will also affect the calculations.

For reference, I verified the behavior in my own org by adding a day:

```
BusinessHours h = [select mondaystarttime, mondayendtime from businesshours where id = '01m50000000Lv2g'];
DateTime startTime = DateTime.newInstance(Date.today().addDays(1), Time.newInstance(h.mondaystarttime.hour(), h.mondaystarttime.minute(), h.mondaystarttime.second(), 0));
DateTime endTime = DateTime.newInstance(Date.today().addDays(1), Time.newInstance(h.mondayendtime.hour(), h.mondayendtime.minute(), h.mondayendtime.second(), 0));
System.debug(BusinessHours.diff(h.id, starttime, endtime));
```

Output:

> 04:12:34.1 (7970375)|USER_DEBUG|[4]|DEBUG|32400000

Which is indeed the expected 9 hours.

Comment: Thanks, understood, but even if I use 8/22/2017 or 8/21/2017, but still diff is o hours

Comment: @JavaSystem Monday business hours are only valid on Monday.

Comment: I use exactly the same code off-course with my Business hour Id, but still diff is 0.

Comment: @JavaSystem Did you check your time zone on the user you are running as? It should match or you will not get a correct answer.

Comment: yes I corrected it now I can see 32400000 in result which is good. But what if in the system we're using two business process for a Milestone on Entitlement process ?

Comment: @JavaSystem The BusinessHours is typically set up for the call center's time zone, because those are the commitment hours. Normally, most organizations only have one or two call centers so this is not a big deal. If you have a ton of time zones, you might need to come up with an alternative plan.

Comment: Thats right. Now I want to implement same for all weekdays and weekends, I dont see we've kind of switch case here to use. what could be the best approach and get business hours based on todays date?